# Delphi XE5 using ftdi jar file in android

Tags: android, delphi-xe5, ftdi

I'm trying to use the FTDI (d2xx) jar file in Delphi XE5 in a android app.
http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm

But I cant get I to work..
Has anybody got any examples on how to import a (this) external jar file?
OR has done this jar file and got it working (so I know it is possible).

I have tried the methods from 
[XE5 - Fun with external Java libraries](https://plus.google.com/+PaulFoster/posts/Tc7viMithGi)
Well I did't have fun, I can't get I to work (easy peasy?).
I don't know what class to load. I have got a assigned "DEXClassLoader" but don't know what class to load. If I look at the dex file I think it should be 'com/ftdi/j2xx/D2xxManager' but I get a "java.lang.classnotfoundException: com/ftdi/j2xx/D2xxManager" message.

The second option I found was the one from Bian long (coderage 8)
I am still investigating this but my demo licence of XE5 is running out.
(I also found the "Android 2 Delphi Import Tool". But i dont know if it works.
If it works I want to buy it. it's only 80 euro)

If I don't get It working we will not update to XE5 (but I want to..) and wait until there is more documentation / samples.

Can anyone help me..

Answer (score 0):

About your second question

> OR has done this jar file and got it working (so I know it is possible))

yes, it is possible. http://www.winsoft.sk/acpftdi.htm
They are selling a source for $60 and have a free demo.
And as an answer to the first question: it's really just an automatic conversion of jar file. I have tried a Java2OP utility from embarcadero and Winsoft's example with minor changes successfully compiled and executed using pas-file generated by Java2OP.exe instead of their library. 
So, if someone want to use FTDI with delphi on android, my way of getting it works for free is:

1. Get Java2OP.exe from http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Java2OP.exe,_the_Native_Bridge_File_Generator_for_Android (you need a registered delphi to download)
2. run it:

> Java2OP.exe -jar d2xx.jar

3. After completion, add d2xx.jar and generated pas file to your project, take the example code from http://www.winsoft.sk/acpftdi.htm or from java examples that comes with d2xx.jar.