# Using ftdi with delphi on android

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, ftdi

I want to use the ftdi lib with delphi on android.
I have read these two posts:

[Delphi XE5 using ftdi jar file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216156/delphi-xe5-using-ftdi-jar-file-in-android/67581360#67581360)

[Firemonkey FTDI XE7 d2xx.jar drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353803/firemonkey-ftdi-xe7-d2xx-jar-drivers)

I have done the two steps, generate pas from jar and include the files to my project.

How to use the lib from the delphi side?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please read about [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Note, that asking for various resources (like e.g. demo code) is not allowed. Edit your question (use the [edit] button beneath the tags) to include the code you have written so far, and indicate what problems you have with that code, so we can advice you how to proceed.

Comment: Did you look at the links provided in the [answer to the SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31922546/3164070) in your first link? i.e. to the WinSoft site, which has a demo example, which may help

Comment: I have checked the examples from winsoft with their solutions (there are more than one different solution they provide) but it won't work with my FTDI device. So I contacted Winsoft now, perhaps there is a general problem with my ftdi device on android.